# Confused about insertion into linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is the code for the node class itself:

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node * next;
  Node(int x) {
    data = x;
    next = NULL;
  }
};
```

The code below inserts a new node at the beginning of a linked list. My question is why the fourth line doesn't mess up the order of the list. If head was previously in the position after new_node, wouldn't setting head equal to new_node mess up the list. When I run the code it works as intended but I'm not sure why.

```
Node *insertAtBegining(Node *head, int newData) {
   Node* new_node = new Node(newData);
   new_node -> next = head;
   head = new_node;
   return head;
}
```

My second question is about the following code which is supposed to insert an item at the end of the linked list. I understand how this one works, I just don't understand why a simplified version of it doesn't also work.

```
Node *insertAtEnd(Node *head, int newData)  {
    Node* new_node = new Node(newData);
    if(head == nullptr){
        head = new_node;
        return head;
    }
    else{
        Node* trav = head;
       while(trav -> next != nullptr){
           trav = trav -> next;
       }    
       trav -> next = new_node;
       return head;
    }
}
```

Simplified version

```
Node *insertAtEnd(Node *head, int newData)  {
    Node* new_node = new Node(newData);
    Node* trav = head;
    while(trav != nullptr){
        trav = trav -> next;
    }
    trav = new_node;
}
```

The simplified version only attaches the last node that you attempt to add to the end of the list. So if you try to attach 1, 2, and 3, only 3 gets added. Shouldn't it be doing the same thing since the trav pointer just becomes that last next pointer?

Comment: The “simplified” version does not return anything.

Comment: `head` is not a node, it's a variable which holds the address of a node. `head = new_node;` does not move any nodes!

Comment: Also note that `head = new_node` doesn't _really_ do anything. You can remove that line, and change the return statement to `return new_node`, and the code will do the same thing.

Comment: The body of the simplified version can be simplified further to the equivalent `Node* trav = new Node(newData);`. Can you spot the problem?

Comment: trav pointer doesn't becomes the last next pointer. It becomes nullptr.

Comment: I think fundamentally what you are not understanding is that none of this code ever copies a node anywhere, If you do `x = y;` and x and y are pointers then all that happens is that the pointer x is made to point to the same thing that the pointer y is pointing at. What x and y are pointing at is unaltered by this. To alter a node you have to write `x->next = ...` or `x->data = ...;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head` is not a node. It's a variable which holds the address of a node.

`head = new_node;` does not move any nodes! It looks at the value in the `new_node` variable (which is the address of a node) and stores that same value into the `head` variable. It doesn't change the list. It only changes the `head` variable.

This line changes the new node. It says that the node after the new node is the one whose address is *currently* in the `head` variable.

```
new_node -> next = head;
```

Note that we don't count the new node as part of the list yet, because you can't get to it from the first node (the one whose address is in the `head` variable).

This line:

```
head = new_node;
```

sets `head` to the address of the new node. *Now* we can say that the new node is in the list, because *now* the "first node" - the one whose address is in the `head` variable - is the new one. Not because we changed the node, but because we changed the `head` variable.

---

Note that `head` is a local variable within the function. If you call this function and you just do `insertAtBeginning(head, 5)` then it won't "change the list" because *your* `head` variable still points at the one it did before. The one in the function got changed, but that variable isn't used any more. You have to do `head = insertAtBeginning(head, 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

**First Code**:

you are creating a `newnode` and for inserting at front you need to set the `next of newnode` to `current head` and then make the `newnode` as `head` (and returning it to store as the current head)

This is what first code is exactly doing. So no problem here.

**Second code (simplified version)**:

- Here you are not storing the `head` (like the 1st code where you returned the head and stored appropriately)
- Also you are traversing till it becomes null (you are past the last element) and creating `newnode`
- you are not linking `newnode` to the end of the linked list

**Solution for Second code (simplified version)**

```cpp
Node *insertAtEnd(Node *head, int newData)  {
    
    Node* new_node = new Node(newData);

    // if this is the first node (head will be NULL)
    if (!head) {
       return new_node; 
    }

    Node* trav = head;
    while(trav->next != nullptr){
        trav = trav -> next;
    }
    trav->next = new_node;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: But at the point where it becomes null, isn't it at the last node's next pointer? I assumed when I did trav = new_node in the simplified version, I was altering the last node's next pointer.

Comment: Yeah it is the last node's next pointer, but programmatically it's NULL , so now you are just setting ```trav (NULL)``` to ```trav (new_node)```. You are not linking the new node with the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

In insertAtEnd, if the list is empty, head will be null. If head is null, then head needs to be set. You can then return the new head.

```
if(trav != nullptr) {do something}
else head = new_node;
```

Now it will update the head but not the next value. You can fix this by stopping on the last value and setting its "next" pointer to the new_node pointer.

```
while(trav->next != nullptr){
    trav = trav -> next;
}
trav->next = new_node;
```

so the end result looks something like this:

```
Node *insertAtEnd(Node *head, int newData)  {
    Node* new_node = new Node(newData);
    Node* trav = head;
    if(trav != nullptr) {
        while(trav->next != nullptr) 
            trav = trav -> next;
        trav->next = new_node;
    }else head = new_node;
    return head;
}
```